# ES6 Arrow Notation with Loops

Tags: javascript, recursion, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

Consider the following bit of code:

```
f=(m,c)=>{m?c()&f(--m,c):0}
```

(thanks to zzzzBov for this little nugget)

which is a "for"-less loop

and the following:

```
a=b=>b+1
```

Given these two snippets, and the fact that:

```
z = 0; f(10,a(z));
```

which I would expect would result in z equating to 10, but instead returns in the JavaScript console the following `"TypeError: c is not a function"`, how would one go about altering this code to ensure that the loop goes ahead, without having to resort to a `while` or `for` loop?

I'm asking this as a matter of education purposes... Hopefully I can get some insight into what can be done...

Comment: `a=b=>b++` makes no sense actually

Comment: @zerkms `a=b=>b++` makes perfect sense when you realize it's equivalent to `a = function(b){return b++;}`

Comment: `a = function(b){return b++;}` makes no sense either. It's exactly the same as `a = function(b) { return b; }`

Comment: @zerkms Edited to make more sense... how's `a=b=>b+1`?

Comment: `a=b=>b+1` makes much more sense, indeed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `f` is taking 2 arguments: `m`, the number to iterate, and `c`, the function to be called `m` times. This means that the second argument, `c` should be a function. For example:

```
f=(m,c)=>{m?c()&f(--m,c):0}


f(15, function() {
 console.log("Hello")
})
```

This will iterate through the `c` function 15 times, calling `console.log` 15 times.

Of course, to achieve what you wanted in the second bit, you could use this:

```
z=0, f(10,()=>z++)
```

This would be a regular arrow function to increase `z` by 1

Take a look at the code [on babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=%0A%2F%2F%20for%20babel%0Avar%20f%3B%0Af%3D(m%2Cc)%3D%3E%7Bm%3Fc()%26f(--m%2Cc)%3A0%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%0Af(2%2C%20function()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20console.log(%22Hello%22)%0A%7D))

Hope I could help!

Comment: Thank you... I knew that there was something I had missed... Implementing the function declaration within the looping function worked a charm... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds you are looking for a folding function (like array `reduce`), not a simple "looping" function that only executes side effects. With that current function, which desugars `f(5, c)` to effectively `c(); c(); c(); c(); c();` you would need to do

```
let z = 0;
f(10,()=>{ z = a(z) });
```

If however you want to make a function that repeatedly applies a function, like `a(a(a(a(a(…)))))`, you would need to write

```
let times = (n, f, s) => n>0 ? times(n-1, f, f(s)) : s;
```

so that you can do

```
let a = b=>b+2
times(5, a, 0) // 10
```